# Azure Database for PostgreSQL server - Deny public network access

Tags: security, azure, postgresql

I have created a private endpoint connection for an azure postgres database, and then set 'Deny public network access' to Yes.

Now, even though my own ip address is still in the Firewall rules list, I would expect the connection to be refused because 'Deny public network access' supercedes any firewall or vnet rules, and only private endpoint connections will be allowed to access this resource.

However, I can still connect to the database from my desktop, with my public ip address.

Any thoughts about what might be going on?

Comment: Any chance you had existing connections open to the DB from your machine? These do not get closed.

Comment: That seems to have been the case.